# How to connect to IP address instead of localhost in php Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony1

In my project I'm using PHP Symfony. My problem is that I want to connect to my IP address in stead of localhost. But I receive this error:

**You don't have permission to access /Symfony 1.1/web/app_dev.php/municipalite on this server.**

Comment: Give more info, you have external static IP and want use it? You want change localhost to 127.0.0.1 ? What you mean 'connect' to my IP ?

Comment: My IP is static. I want to changel localhost to my IP adress. the URL must contain my address IP instead of localhost. This is a part of my code:

Comment: If you want to use your static IP (on your local machine as server) you should start from setuping apache2.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `web/app_dev.php` which contains checking of your IP and denying access when you're accessing from ip other than localhost.

You will have to add your IP to list of permitted IPs and it should work fine then. I'm not sure about symfony 1.1 but in symfony 1.4 this part of file looks like that:

```
if (!in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', '::1')))
{
  die('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}
```

so add your ip to `array('127.0.0.1', '::1')` array